# Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm reading a book [Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X). In chapter 3 (Design Principles and Patterns), the book states:

> *Inversion of control* (IOC) is an application of DIP that refers to situations where generic code controls the execution of more specific and external components.

I disagree. I think DIP is an application of IOC. In Martin Fowler's article [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) he states:

> As a result I think we need a more specific name for this pattern. Inversion of Control is too generic a term, and thus people find it confusing. As a result with a lot of discussion with various IoC advocates we settled on the name Dependency Injection.

To me that indicates that DIP is a specific term for a specific application of IOC.

What say you?

Comment: There's a vote to close for the reason "off topic". Huh???

Comment: Yes; off topic moved to Programmers. The alternative was Not Constructive, which this appears to also fit pretty well.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954913/dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-terminology

Comment: I guess the reason I'm asking is that a respected book, written by a respected author and architect, says something differently than what I see others saying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inversion of Control < Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226605/inversion-of-control-dependency-injection)